VS Code crash on Ubuntu 22.04
OS : Ubuntu 22.04 on a VM (Parallels) on an ARM64 machine (Macbook M3)
Problem: Clicking on 'open folder' or any other 'open' results in VS code crashing.
Already tried:

Reinstalling VS code
Reinstalling Ubuntu
code --disable-gpu

Logs: code --verbose shows this:
[696186:0429/102103.810923:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 RunAutomaticTasks: waited some extra time, but no update of tasks configuration", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[main 2024-04-29T17:21:10.097Z] menubarService#updateMenubar 1
assertion failed [rem_idx != -1]: Unable to find existing allocation for shared memory segment to unmap
(VMAllocationTracker.cpp:745 remove_shared_mem)
[696186:0429/102111.715352:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(997)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[696186:0429/102111.715418:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1367)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[696186:0429/102111.724661:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 CommandService#executeCommand workbench.action.keepEditor", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[696186:0429/102111.728411:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 CommandService#executeCommand workbench.action.files.openFolder", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[main 2024-04-29T17:21:11.731Z] [DialogMainService]: request to acquire file dialog lock {
  title: 'Open Folder',
  buttonLabel: undefined,
  filters: undefined,
  defaultPath: '/home/parallels',
  properties: [ 'multiSelections', 'openDirectory', 'createDirectory' ]
}
[main 2024-04-29T17:21:11.731Z] [DialogMainService]: new file dialog lock created {
  title: 'Open Folder',
  buttonLabel: undefined,
  filters: undefined,
  defaultPath: '/home/parallels',
  properties: [ 'multiSelections', 'openDirectory', 'createDirectory' ]
}
assertion failed [rem_idx != -1]: Unable to find existing allocation for shared memory segment to unmap
(VMAllocationTracker.cpp:745 remove_shared_mem)

